# Default values for Honeycomb

Tags: android

Is there a list of default values for Honeycomb text sizes so I can use them in my application for consistency with other built in applications? I tried to apply `Holo theme` but this has no affect for text sizes, they are as small as on the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "Holo theme" for phones today, as Honeycomb is only for tablets.

You are welcome to examine the Honeycomb styles resources in your SDK to see what various text sizes are listed as. I see many listed in `res/values/styles.xml` (e.g., dialog title bars are `18sp`). You might start with the `Theme.Holo` definition in `res/values/themes.xml`, find the item you want, then look up the value in `res/values/styles.xml`.

Comment: This is a good place to start, but if you're looking for consistency in text appearances, reference the current theme in your TextViews like this: `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"` Available theme attributes to reference for text include `textAppearance`, `textAppearanceLarge`, `textAppearanceMedium`, `textAppearanceSmall`, and `*Inverse` variants of each that have inverted text color for placing on a contrasting background.

Comment: yeah, this is actually what I was looking for.